# How to Define Contact-us cms page from admin panel and also how to submit data to email

Tags: magento-1.9

Contact Us page in cms is defined but the form is not printing when we open the url of linked contact us page.
As I debug myself I found that It need a to call from admin panel. Dont know how to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this code in your cms page inside content option. Its working for me.

```
 {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Is the answer is helpfull??

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest this one

for sending mail to defined email id you need to chage this line in contacts/form.phtml

```
<form action="<?php echo this->getFormdata(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

replace the above line with this code

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post'); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```